# Issue with 2D collision bitmaps

Tags: java, android, collision-detection

The bitmap A has a position which is its X/Y position is static, bitmap B is  moving bitmap which moves from the bottom of the screen to where ever the user touches on screen. When the moving bitmap reaches the static bitmap however it is not recognized as a collision, the moving bitmap uses float which i round off and the static bitmap uses int. Below is a snippet of code, I want to figure out what is needed to be changed for my bitmaps crossing paths to be considered a collision

```
                  canvas.drawBitmap(rock2, 70, 32, null);
    //this is where it checks to see if the moving bitmaps y coordinate is matched to the Y coordinate of the static bitmap
   if(canvas.getHeight() - Math.round(animY*-1) == (canvas.getHeight() - (canvas.getHeight()-32))){

        Log.d("ALERT", "COLLIDE");

      }
    //the Y value is *-1 because the moving bitmap is starting from the bottom of the screen so this converts the value to positive value
```

I wonder if my calculations are off, or I am going about this collision the wrong way. Below is my movement code snippet

```
               //UP Y ANIMATION
    if(animY*-1 < canvas.getHeight() && !bumpY){

        animY += speedY;

        //IF ROCK IS NOT AT EXTREME LEFT OR EXTREME RIGHT KEEP ON TRACK
        if(animX < (canvas.getWidth()/2) || animX*-1 < (canvas.getWidth()/2) && !bumpX){
            animX += speedX;
            //IF ROCK HITS EDGE LEFT/RIGHT RETURN TO SENDER (INDICATE BUMP)
            if(animX*-1 > (canvas.getWidth()/2) - rock.getWidth()/2 || animX > (canvas.getWidth()/2) - rock.getWidth()/2){
                bumpX = true;
                bumpY = true;
            }
        }

        //IF Y HITS TOP OF SCREEN
        if(animY*-1 > canvas.getHeight()){
            bumpY = true;
        }
    }

    //DOWN Y ANIMATION
    if(animY < 0 && bumpY){ 

        //REVERSE DIRECTION OF Y
         animY  -= speedY;

         //IF ROCK HITS TOP OR SIDE REVERSE X DIRECTION
         if(bumpX || bumpY)
                animX -= speedX;

         //IF AT STARTING POINT
         if(animY > 0){
                bumpY = false;
                bumpX = false;
            }
    }

             //in an ontouch method where the X and Y values are calculated
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            finalX = event.getX() - (cross.getWidth() / 2);
            finalY = event.getY() - (cross.getHeight() / 2);
            moveToX = finalX - startX;
            moveToY = finalY - startY;
            speedX = moveToX / 50;
            speedY = moveToY / 50;
            break;
```

Any tips would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: have you added in Log.d messages to display what the rock's coordinates are, with respect to time? can't be sure, but i think something is wonky with the way you calculated the "if(canvas.getHeight() - Math.round(animY*-1) == (canvas.getHeight() - (canvas.getHeight()-32)))" ... and print that out too, to see what the result is at each step

Comment: the moving bitmap doesnt move in perfect order, i logged that movement as well. Depending on how for from the starting point you click the collision is detected and logged in cat, if you touch closer to starting point the method i used to calculate works but further away and it doesnt. Maybe a rounding issue? if so I am in need of some direction lol. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry if this is a dumb answer, but should your check be:

```
if(canvas.getHeight() - Math.round(animY*-1) >= (canvas.getHeight() - (canvas.getHeight()-32))){
```

instead? (change the "==" to ">=" ) otherwise you are only checking for when the rock lands EXACTLY on (canvas.getheight -32), rather than checking past it

Comment: Thanks for your addition, that is a point but I do want to check for one the moving rock hits the static one exactly. Both X and Y that is

Comment: sorry for misreading the question. gotcha. now i'm also starting to think that it's a rounding issue... but also - does the rock have to land exactly on? or could it be +/- 10 points off? because getting the rock to be EXACTLY on a spot is a bit hard... from a user perspective

Comment: It just needs to be touching the other edge or border of the static bitmap, so the range would be the total width or height or the static bitmap. Yes I am thinking rounding has part to play definitely, so I was hoping some tweak advice could be made to my current code to help me along hehe

Comment: sorry i'm kinda rusty with Android... but what's the coordinate system like again? is (0,0) on the bottom left of a portrait screen? as for rounding, the reason you are getting truncated values is possibly because the speed set to "speedY = moveToY / 50;" as opposed a decimal "50.0"

Comment: (0,0) is top left, the starting point of the moving object is in the center and bottom of the screen, the static bitmaps are near the top. Hmm well the movement calculations are in float values depending on how far from the starting point you click the rock moves faster or slower

Comment: Skimmed your code again. hmm... what does "animY" print out to be right before the check for collision? sorry, kinda hard for me to debug without the whole code. but there's probably a much better programmer than me staring at this post

Comment: your doing the correct steps to debug it cuz that represent the Y axis, that goes in increments of 3 or 4 or 5 depending on how far away from the starting point you have touched. so in this situation it jumps over 32 if i click far from the starting point and hits it if i touch near

Comment: in this case, i don't think there's anything wrong with your code, because the collision WILL happen. However, it's just that since you've made the target so small, it's almost impossible to touch it exactly on. is that the concern? because then, you should maybe change to check for if animY and animX is just anywhere near.